# Does spaCy deal with subscripts and superscripts?

Tags: html, tags, spacy, subscript, superscript

I have some HTML texts that include `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags. I am wondering how I should convert them into plain text so that they will be correctly processed by current spaCy models.

Should I convert  and  as something like `a_b` and `a^b` to preserve subscript and superscripts? Thanks.